# How can an electron shell hold more than two electrons?

Tags: electrons, atoms, orbitals

The Pauli Exclusion principle states

> in an atom or molecule, no two electrons can have the same four electronic quantum numbers. As an orbital can contain a maximum of only two electrons, the two electrons must have opposing spins.

So how can some electron shells have up to 6 electrons or more? Take the electron configuration of Magnesium. The 2p shell holds 6 electrons. How is this possible? Can you have multiple orbitals in a single electron shell?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44055/discussion-on-question-by-easypeasy-how-can-an-electron-shell-hold-more-than-two).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A "shell" is the term for all states with the same [principal quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_quantum_number) $n$, but in each shell there are also possible different values for the [angular momentum quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_quantum_number) $0\leq \ell \leq n$, the [magnetic quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number) $-\ell \leq m_\ell \leq \ell$ and the [spin quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_quantum_number) $m_s\in\{-1/2,1/2\}$.

So for $n>1$, 6 electrons in a shell do not violate the Pauli exclusion principle.

Comment: Note that the OP seems to be using "shell" to mean definite $n$ and $\ell$, since they talk about the "2p shell".   (I think most sources would call this a "subshell" instead.)  Your logic is still fine for any subshell with $\ell \neq 0$, though.

Comment: this is not an exact answer to the question. How did you got 17 upvotes for that ?